# Mediawiki Edit Login Page

Tags: mediawiki

I am managing a MediaWiki Page that is only logged into by admins, but in order to create a single signon I use the MediaWiki SpecialUserlogin.php as the login base.

Now, I am trying to alter the main login form, one of that changes made was

```
$template->set( 'remember', false );
$template->set( 'canremember', false ) ;
```

To get rid of the `Remember me` check box.  But now I've been instructed to remove the `Your Domain` drop down menu, I tried to change

```
$template->set( 'domain', false );
```

But it didn't respond the same as the `canremember` and the `remember` values from above.  Has anyone successfully gotten rid of the Your Domain line in the SpecialUserlogin page?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was able to set a CSS variable `td.mw-input select {visibility: hidden; margin-bottom: -20px}` that made the drop down menu dissappear, and the submit button raise up.